# How to split a very long string

Tags: java, string

I have big file (about 30mb) and here the code I use to read data from the file

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                try {
                    String line = br.readLine();
                    while (line != null) {
                        sb.append(line).append("\n");
                        line = br.readLine();
                    }
```

Then I need to split the content I read, so I use

```
String[] inst = sb.toString().split("GO");
```

The problem is that sometimes the sub-string is over the maximum String length and I can't get all the data inside the string. How can I get rid of this?

Thanks

Comment: What do you  mean by *sub-string is over the maximum string length*?

Comment: 30MB of String?!?! Are you serious?! What are you doing?

Comment: I guess he just got the binary code of some file (maybe a big PDF), and want to manipulate it?

Comment: you can keep a check on number of words/characters you are adding into substring.

Comment: well first of all god knows what makes you deal with such a huge string , by the way , break your string in to smaller string , store in an array , split all thr entries in your array , then try appeding ( this appending will need a deeper concern )

Comment: @Fabinout: I have some difficulties in understanding any scenario where it makes sense to read a binary file in a large string and then split it with the text "GO". If this is really the case here, the OP has some serious design problems

Comment: @user1567896 Or maybe it is a serious question, simplified as much as possible, coming from an experienced developper. Guess we'll never know ;)

Answer (score 1):

`Scanner s = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter("GO");` and use `s.next()`

Answer (score 0):

WHY PART:- The erroneous result may be the outcome of non contiguous heap segment as the CMS collector doesn't de-fragment memory.

(It does not answer your how to solve part though).

You may opt for loading the whole string partwise, i.e using substring